# Create a New attribute table in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table

I am trying to create a new table of attributes for later purposes, in arcGIS but just an empty one, How can i do this? I also have it as an Excel format, but I don't know if there is any way to export it into ArcMap?

Comment: This might help: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Adding%20and%20viewing%20tables%20in%20ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

I understend  that you are trying to create a empty feature class. You have to create a new shapefile ( or feature clases inside geodatabase) and define the type of geometry that will be store. To define the fields you can import the schema from your record sheet.